# Reliable method to check if device can send SMS with current connectivity

Tags: android, sms

I have an application that send SMS automatically to a remote server. I want to check if the phone is connected to a network capable to send SMS before calling the SMSManager.send() method.

I tried the following method :

```
TelephonyManager tlm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
boolean hasNetwork = tlm.getNetworkType() != android.telephony.TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
```

Unfortunately, this method works on some phones like Acer or Nexus but not on others like some Sony Xperia.

I then tried an other approach :check if the phone is connected to antennas (and I assume that there is network when connected to an antenna)

```
private static boolean isSmsNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager tlm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    boolean hasNetwork = false;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        // new API
        List<CellInfo> listCellInfo = tlm.getAllCellInfo();
        if (listCellInfo != null && !listCellInfo.isEmpty()) {
            for (CellInfo cellInfo : listCellInfo) {
                if (cellInfo.isRegistered()) {
                    hasNetwork = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // old API
        List<NeighboringCellInfo> listNeighboringCellInfo = tlm.getNeighboringCellInfo();
        if (listNeighboringCellInfo != null && !listNeighboringCellInfo.isEmpty()) {
            hasNetwork = true;
        }
    }
    return hasNetwork;
}
```

This method is also unreliable , it works on Nexus, Xperia, but not on Acer phones (for example)...

So the question is : Is there a reliable method to check if a phone is really capable to send SMS with the current connectivity?